# i want to set an SVG shape as a div background with centered text . And make the svg responsive too

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, frontend

I am encountering challenges with positioning an SVG background and centering text over it. When using background-position: cover, parts of the SVG are getting cropped. On the other hand, using background-position: contain with background-repeat: no-repeat leaves white space around the SVG. Additionally, **when resizing the screen, the SVG shape exhibits unexpected behavior.** I have made multiple attempts to resolve these issues without success.

```
    <section className="flex items-center px-12 my-24 text-white ">
  <div className="w-[60%] space-y-10  flex flex-col ">
    <div className="relative bg-[url('/img/hero/hero-text-shape.svg')] bg-contain bg-no-repeat flex justify-center items-center h-52 w-full min-h-[10rem]">
      <h1 className="text-5xl md:text-4xl text-[#EEA00C] relative xl:-left-[9%]">
        Gaming More.
        <span className="text-[#9BFCEB]">Earn Limitless.</span>
      </h1>
    </div>

    <p className="text-xl font-semibold leading[125%] max-w-[39rem]">
      Play your favourite game and be the part of the ultimate experience
      with world fastest Network protocol.
    </p>
    <div className="flex items-center gap-5 buttons">
      <a className="px-4 py-2 font-bold text-black bg-[#9BFCEB] rounded-lg opacity-90 hover:opacity-100 hover:cursor-pointer">
        Access Beta
      </a>
      <a className="px-4 py-2 font-bold border-2 border-[#9BFCEB] rounded-lg text-white opacity-90 hover:opacity-100 hover:cursor-pointer">
        Access Beta
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className=" w-[50%] hero-img block ">
    <img className="w-full" src="/img/hero/hero.svg" alt="" />
  </div>
</section>
```

[Working good on desktop size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clKQc.png)

[Not working on small size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htlnr.png)

I want anyone to provide professional guidance on the correct approach to address this challenges?
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You have to decide what you want on viewports with differing aspect ratios. cover/contain/width:100%and so on. The natural aspect ratio of the image can’t be the same for all of them.

Comment: I want to use the cover but the Svg get cropped in sides that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I recommend you export different SVGs and use them on different screens.

Like one for mobile and one for tablet and pc

Comment: How would you accommodate all the different viewport aspect ratios?

Comment: The general picture is going to be almost either a rectangle shape or a square shape. That's why I suggested using two or three different SVGs so he won't have too much overlapping and miss placing the text inside the SVG.